# SQL, Impala: why can't I do two counts on one query

Tags: sql, count, impala

I tried to do two counts for different columns in my query:

```
select  count(distinct color) as cid,
  count(distinct entity) as eid from my_table
```

The above query wouldn't work with the following errors:

```
SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: 
all DISTINCT aggregate functions need to have the same set of parameters as count(DISTINCT color); deviating function: count(DISTINCT entity)
), Query: select  count(distinct color) as cid,
  count(distinct entity) as eid from my_table
```

However, if I just do one count the query would work. Why is that? Is it possible for me to do two counts in one query?
Thanks!

Comment: what does *doesn't work* mean? do you get an error? or an incorrect result? or something else?

Comment: updated with error message

Comment: have you tried `count(distinct color) over(), count(distinct entity) over()`?

Comment: Just tried, here is the error: Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: 
DISTINCT not allowed in analytic function: count(DISTINCT color)
)

Answer (score 4):

Impala does not currently support multiple *count distinct* expressions within the same query, see [IMPALA-110](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-110). This is a requested feature, but is surprisingly hard to implement so hasn't been added yet.

For now, if you do not need precise accuracy, you can produce an estimate of the distinct values for a column by specifying `NDV(column)`; a query can contain multiple instances of `NDV(column)`. To make Impala automatically rewrite `COUNT(DISTINCT)` expressions to `NDV()`, enable the `APPX_COUNT_DISTINCT` query option (see the [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_appx_count_distinct.html)).

Answer (score 1):

An update on this - Impala 3.1 (released Nov 2018) adds support for multiple distinct aggregate functions in a new query block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work in Impala, but you can do `count(distinct)` using window functions and conditional aggregation.  So, this query:

```
select count(distinct color) as cid,
       count(distinct entity) as eid
from my_table ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
select sum(case when seqnum_color = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cid,
       sum(case when seqnum_entity = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as eid
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by color order by color) as seqnum_color,
             row_number() over (partition by entity order by entity) as seqnum_entity
      from my_table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Great idea :D. Unfortunately my Impala is running out of memory this way.

Comment: For impala, suggest use NDV(entity) instead of count(distinct entity).

Comment: @Decula . . . The OP uses `count(distinct)` and so presumably wants an accurate distinct count.  `NDV()` is fine but it is approximate.